# How to get number of documents BY filter of a collection in Android Cloud firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Assume that I have a collection named "students" below:

- collection `students` has 3 fields:

  - name
  - age
  - status (0: passed, 1: failed, -1: not tested)

('status' field describles the student passed or failed or Notyet tested)

- The collection `students` has 1000 documents with different 'status'
- Now I want to get the count of students who [passed/failed/not tested] the exam
- And whenever 'status' of a student is updated 0/1/-1 then I will have to re-count.

How can I solve this?
I shouldn't query all data for everytime update because it will cause high cost. NOTICE that, I want to count base on the 'status' field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're describing is a common use-case, and covered in the Firebase documentation on [aggregation queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/aggregation). To make these (cost) efficient at scale, you'll want to store the aggregated value in the database, and then update it on every write operation.

The update can be performed from the client, but is more commonly performed from within a Cloud Function. The documentation linked covers both approaches.